# Can not call method of other class from static method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At first, i have a class which in **app/workes/** like this:

```
class SendMailTask
  include Resque::Plugins::Status
  require 'mail'
  def perform
    ...
  end
```

And as a controller, i have class UsersController and a static method like bellow:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def self.check
    ...
    ::SendMailTask.create(to: [] << @to_addresses,  subject: @subject, body: @body)
  end
```

When i call method UsersController.check() from other file, i received the error: **"in `block in check': uninitialized constant SendMailTask (NameError)"**

But from other controller, i can call SendMailTask  normally:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ...
    ::SendMailTask.create(to: [] << @to_addresses,  subject: @subject, body: @body)
  end
```

I try to add this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/workers)
```

to **application.rb** and try to add

> require './SendMailTask'

at the begin of file **users_controller.rb** but it does not work.

Please help me resolve this error. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameError means the your `SendMailTask` isn't loaded. so you will have to load that. so couple of things.

1. I noticed a typo `workes`, so please verify the file name is correct. By Convention, it should be located at `app/workers/send_mail_task.rb`. so kindly double-triple check the same.
2. About `require './SendMailTask'`, this is wrong. Instead it would be `send_mail_task` as requires works on filenames & not class names.
3. if still get an error, then please post your `$LOAD_PATH` to see you are requiring the file relative to the defined `$LOAD_PATH`
4. Instead of `require`, I prefer to use `require_dependency` as it works with code-reloading etc. so if you have trouble with auto-loading, just stick that require_dependency on top of the file, this will hint rails to load the file BEFORE running the controller.

Comment: Thanks you.
When i add "require 'sendmail_task'" it can run normally